# Getting a simple string response ends in a MalformedJsonException

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a simple POST request for registering a location in our backend which should respond a string with the locationId and an unique registration code which gets shown for other stuff. In Postman the request looks like: `120:B6IRDAEDZ82BCDMP9QUK` which is fine.

So, I've built a retrofit request which simply does the same:

```kotlin
    @POST("remote_montage/set_credentials/{locationId}")
    suspend fun getRegistrationQrCode(
        @Path("locationId") locationId: Int
    ): Response<String>
```

Now, if I call it in my repository, it throws me this Error

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 4 path $
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:590)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:41)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have no Idea what this means. What Columns? What value? What Line?

Answer (score 1):

The `GsonConverterFactory` you are providing to retrofit is looking at the response and finding that it is invalid JSON.

You should use `ScalarsConverterFactory` which is designed to convert string responses

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'`

and add it to your retrofit builder

`.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())`

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one converter factory or can scalars handle all my other requests aswell?

Comment: It is but a quick Google suggests that it may be not quite straight forward to manage. You may want to make life easy for yourself by having 2 retrofit instances, one for json and one for strings

Comment: I have one another function with a string in it and that works without problems. Setting up a whole other instance and loading a complete new dependency just for one request is very ridiculous...